# Change layout for custom keyboard

Tags: android, android-custom-keyboard

I'm trying to create a keyboard for android. So far I've created the classic keyboard with lines containing letters.

This is the file keyboard_view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/keyboardview"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/primary_text_dark">
</android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView>
```

This is the file for display raw

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="3px"
    android:verticalGap="3px"
    android:keyHeight="60dp"
    android:keyTextColor="#ffffff">

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="113" android:keyLabel="q" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="w"/>
        <Key android:codes="101" android:keyLabel="e"/>
        <Key android:codes="114" android:keyLabel="r"/>
        <Key android:codes="116" android:keyLabel="t"/>
        <Key android:codes="121" android:keyLabel="y"/>
        <Key android:codes="117" android:keyLabel="u"/>
        <Key android:codes="105" android:keyLabel="i"/>
        <Key android:codes="111" android:keyLabel="o"/>
        <Key android:codes="112" android:keyLabel="p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="97" android:keyLabel="a" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="115" android:keyLabel="s"/>
        <Key android:codes="100" android:keyLabel="d"/>
        <Key android:codes="102" android:keyLabel="f"/>
        <Key android:codes="103" android:keyLabel="g"/>
        <Key android:codes="104" android:keyLabel="h"/>
        <Key android:codes="106" android:keyLabel="j"/>
        <Key android:codes="107" android:keyLabel="k"/>
        <Key android:codes="108" android:keyLabel="l"/>
        <Key android:codes="35,64" android:keyLabel="\# \@" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>

</Keyboard>
```

My question is: how can I change the layout to put the keys around the edge of the smartphone? Example: create a circular layout for keyboard 
Image: [circular keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57j5R.png)